# Background changer to refresh

Tags: php, html, css, performance

I need a script to change the background Color every refresh. 
I looked everywhere for this code/script but no luck.

Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: have an ajax call by default on refresh which returns you the new color and set the background using javascript.

Comment: THe color is supposed to be random?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look this link https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/random-hex-color/

PHP

```
<?php 
    $rand = array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
    $color = '#'.$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)];
?>
```

HTML

```
<body style="background: <?php echo $color; ?>;">
```

Comment: Good script But i want to put my colors in background. Dont work like `<?php 
    $rand = array('f9b0ff', 'b0d0ff', 'd0ffaf');
    $color = '#'.$rand[rand(0,1)].$rand[rand(0,1)].$rand[rand(0,1)];
?>`

Comment: Just saying, but from the link you posted the second option is quite faster since it only makes 1 rand value, and print it as hexadecimal `<?php printf( "#%06X\n", mt_rand( 0, 0xFFFFFF )); ?>`

Comment: @OvidiuCristianPrisacaru that wont work. since you're getting 3 parameters from the `$rand` that each as full hexa color code

Comment: Thank you for help. Work this code `<?php 
    $rand = array('f9b0ff', 'f9e0aa', 'b0d0ff', 'ffb0b0', '00a0f0', 'ed1c24', 'b4a996', 'a4c639', 'b52e31', '629aa9', 'e04646', '788cb6');
    $color = '#'.$rand[rand(0,12)];
?>
`   `<body style="background: <?php echo $color; ?>;">`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with JavaScript also. Try this code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer>
   function getRandomColor() {
       var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
       var color = '#';
       for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
           color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
       }
       return color;
   }


   if (sessionStorage.getItem("reload_count")) {
      var reloadCount = sessionStorage.getItem("reload_count");
      var reloadCount = Number(reloadCount);
      var reloadCountOld = Number(reloadCount);
      sessionStorage.setItem("reload_count", reloadCount += 1);
   } else {
      sessionStorage.setItem("reload_count", 1);
   }

   if (reloadCount > reloadCountOld) {
      var hexColor = getRandomColor();
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = hexColor;
   }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just posting to have the hexadecimal calculation for both PHP and Javascript approach.

PHP

```
$color = sprintf( "#%06X\n", mt_rand( 0, 0xFFFFFF ));
```

Javascript

```
var color = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * parseInt('FFFFFF', 16)).toString(16);
```

Color will have the usual hexadecimal color code (ex: `#ea32f0`), than just use that to set the body background.

Comment: Work and this code from the top. `<?php 
    $rand = array('f9b0ff', 'f9e0aa', 'b0d0ff', 'ffb0b0', '00a0f0', 'ed1c24', 'b4a996', 'a4c639', 'b52e31', '629aa9', 'e04646', '788cb6');
    $color = '#'.$rand[rand(0,12)];
?>` :D Thank you for help mloureiro